# android: how to see items that i pick on ListView (more than one)

Tags: android

how to see items that i pick on ListView ?

i have this code:

```
ListView lstView = getListView();
lstView.setChoiceMode(2); //CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE
lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, items));

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    parent.setItemChecked(position, parent.isItemChecked(position));
    TT.setText(items[position]);
    }
```

when i press the Button - how to see items that i pick (i pick more than one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the checked items through: `getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();`

For example:

```
SparseBooleanArray checked = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
    if(checked.get(i))
        Log.i("CheckedItem", ids.get(checked.indexOfKey(i)));
}
```

Comment: @Frankenstein Are you making fun or really not knowing? :)

Comment: no really never knew about listview's this functionality..and right now checking it.

Comment: @Frankenstein yes listview provides ChoiceMode, just check `setChoiceMode()` method of listview.

Answer (score 1):

you can get checked items id by :

```
long[] idsOfCheckedItems = linesListView.getCheckItemIds();
```